# How to pull submodules in .gitmodule?

Tags: git

I added a new submodule to my Git repository, which updated .gitmodules for the parent module. After I push .gitmodules, what do my teammates need to do to get the new submodule?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having your teammates do

```
git pull
git submodule update --init
```

should do the trick. This will update all submodules to point to the newly pulled submodule commit value, and also initialize the submodule if necessary.